# 2nd or 3rd conditional

Tags: conditionals

If only we ______________ a three instead of four. We'd be rich!
-chose
-had chosen

It's a task of a quiz I found on the internet, so I selected "chose", cuz it looks like a structure of 2nd conditional. But the correct answer was "had chosen". Can't figure out the logic. Please help.

Comment: _Chose_ (Past - what I think you are calling the 2nd conditional) is a _realis_ condition - one that might or might not hold. _Had chosen_ (Past perfect - your 3rd conditional) is _irrealis_ (or "counter factual"): it is known not to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it easier to see the correct answer when we use another word in replacement for the one we are having difficulty to understand.

---

If only we ______________ a three instead of four. We'd be rich!

decide; had decided.

---

> If only we decide a three instead of four. We'd be rich!

This cannot be correct: *in this context* ***we will be rich if we decide 3 not 4***.

---

> If only we had decided a three instead of four. We'd be rich!

***Had** is referring to something that was **possessed in the past**...but
not now.*

*in this context* ***we would have been be rich if we decide 3 not 4.***

---

choose:
**chose** | chosen Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/choose)

**to decide what you want from two or more things or possibilities:**